# Curl status response treatment on Jenkins, unable to abort pipeline execution

Tags: curl, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a scripted pipeline (Jenkinsfile) where I want to grab a CURL response (if 200 ok, move on. Otherwise, abort the job). I`m struggling with the curl syntax within the pipeline stage meant for that:

```
stage('Getting getting external API') {
steps {
  script{
        /* groovylint-disable-next-line LineLength */
        final String url = "curl -X 'GET' \ 'https://my-endpoint-test/operations/promote/Approved' \ -H 'accept: */*'"


        final def (String code) = sh(script: "curl -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' $url", returnStdout: true)
                    
                    echo "HTTP response status code: $code"
                    /* groovylint-disable-next-line NestedBlockDepth */
                    if (code != "200") {
                        error ('URL status different of 200. Exiting script.')
                    } 
        }
    }
}
```

I think I`m not in the right direction with this URL, it complains about the ""after GET and before "-H".

```
    WorkflowScript: 54: unexpected char: '\' @ line 54, column 47.

   l String url = "curl -X 'GET' \ 'https:/

                                 ^1 error
```

Also, could you advise on a more simple way of aborting this pipeline, depending on the http status response?

Comment: [A backslash in a Java/Groovy string is to escape special characters](http://www.groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_escaping_special_characters). What do you try to achieve with these ` \ ` ? Furthermore, the variable is namend `url` but contains a complete `curl` command, which you then interpolate into another `curl` command. Have you ever thought about using [declarative pipelines](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#declarative-versus-scripted-pipeline-syntax)?

Comment: @GeroldBroser. Yeah I was precisely struggling with these backlashes. They come out the Curl formatting , as seen on Swagger. Makes a lot sense. I did not t know know to treat that. And , yes: I considered declaritive pipelines . I am just trying to folow some sort of a standards in this project. But I will definetily give it a try in case scripted doesn`t suits our needs.

Comment: Scripted pipelines suit more needs in general. But I haven't seen any Jenkins project in years that needed such. There are so many plugins available as pipeline steps now:  https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curl cmd is incorrect.

```
stage('Getting getting external API') {
  steps {
    script{

      cmd = """
          curl -s -X GET -H 'accept: */*' -w '{http_code}' \
              'https://my-endpoint-test/operations/promote/Approved' 
      """

      status_code = sh(script: cmd, returnStdout: true).trim()
      // must call trim() to remove the default trailing newline
                  
      echo "HTTP response status code: ${status_code}"

      if (status_code != "200") {
          error('URL status different of 200. Exiting script.')
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work pretty well. I'm not sure about the output tho, Because the ${status_code} variable returns something bigger than just the status number it self: HTTP response status code: {"statusCode":500,"message":"Internal server error"}{http_code}